# how to get first and last day of each month for past 4 years from current date in IBM DB2?

Tags: database, db2, db2-400

I have written the following code to get past 4 years every first and end of month dates from current date in db2.

```
WITH tempdateseries (StartDate,EndDate) AS (
SELECT
    DATE(1) + (YEAR(CURRENT DATE)-5) YEARS AS StartDate,
    LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 4 YEARS) AS EndDate
FROM
    sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    StartDate + 1 MONTH,
    EndDate
FROM
    tempdateseries
WHERE
    StartDate < LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTHS)
    AND EndDate < LAST_DAY(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTHS)) 
    SELECT
    *
FROM
    tempdateseries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T (STARTDATE) AS 
(
VALUES CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAY
  UNION ALL
SELECT STARTDATE - 1 MONTH
FROM T
WHERE CURRENT DATE < STARTDATE - 1 MONTH + 4 YEAR
)
SELECT STARTDATE, STARTDATE + 1 MONTH - 1 DAY ENDDATE
FROM T
ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

The result is:

```
|STARTDATE |ENDDATE   |
|----------|----------|
|2020-05-01|2020-05-31|
|2020-04-01|2020-04-30|
|2020-03-01|2020-03-31|
|2020-02-01|2020-02-29|
|2020-01-01|2020-01-31|
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice one @Mark Barinstein...

Taking a ride in your approach, but intrudocing two new useful functions from recent releases..

[DATE_TRUNC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061949.html) and [LAST_DAY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053630.html)

```
WITH T (STARTDATE) AS  
( 
VALUES DATE(DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', CURRENT DATE ) )
  UNION ALL 
SELECT STARTDATE - 1 MONTH 
FROM T 
WHERE CURRENT DATE < STARTDATE - 1 MONTH + 4 YEAR 
) 
SELECT STARTDATE, LAST_DAY(STARTDATE) ENDDATE 
FROM T 
ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC 
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: The question is tagged as [db2-400]. This means, that DB2 for IBM i is used. But there are no `DATE_TRUNC` or `FIRST_DAY` functions there as in recent Db2 for LUW versions. [LAST_DAY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzscalastday.htm) only. My solution works on all 3 DB2 platforms.

Comment: Hi @mark,  I did not notice the db2-400 tag. Yes your version works everywhere. It was not my intention to steal it,  Was just providing same functionality as yours,  by using newer functions that normally most people don't realize they are there. I have provided the URLs for both functions to the v11.1 documentation. they are there for Db2-LUW.  My object in posting it, was just to enrich the content about his question, as there are new functions added that does exactly what he asked for. Nothing else.